# $X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$, $U = X+Y$. What are $E[X|U], E[Y|U]$?

Tags: probability

$X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$. X, Y are independent.  $U = X+Y$.

What are the values of $E[X|U], E[Y|U]$?

I understand $E[X|U] + E[Y|U] = U$, but I'm not sure how to move forward...

Comment: [Also asked on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148048/6633) where it has received two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, $X, Y$ and $X+Y$ are jointly Gaussian.

If $A$ and $B$ are jointly Gaussian, then $E[A|B] = E[A] + cov(A,B) cov(B,B)^{-1} (B- E[B])$. See section 3.3.2 and 3.4 in [these notes](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/randomprocJan14.pdf) for an example.

Note that $cov(A,B) = E[(A-E[A])(B-E[B])]$ so $cov(B,B) = var(B)$.

Note that $var U = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ and $cov(X, U) = cov(X, X+Y) = cov(X,X) + cov(X,Y) = \sigma_1^2 + 0 = \sigma_1^2$ by independent implies uncorrelated, and $cov(Y, U) = \sigma_2^2$. Now, plug in $A=X$ and $B=U$ to get $E[X|U]$ into that formula, and $A=Y$ and $B=U$ to get $E[Y|U]$ (or just use the fact that $E[Y|U] = E[U-X|U] = U  - E[X|U]$).

If you want to avoid using that formula (or knowing anything about jointly gaussian), find $f(x|u)$ by finding  $f(x,u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x  \partial u} P(X \leq x, U \leq u)$ (write it in terms of an integral of $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ over the appropriate region), note that $U \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ since its the sum of 2 independent Gaussians and use $f(x|u) = \frac{f(x,u)}{f(u)}$. You'll see $X|U=u$ is a gaussian with a certain mean and that will give you $E[X|U=u]$.